# Differrent output for the solidus symbol (/) inside math mode

Tags: macros, output

I have asked before how to create a macro for a new division symbol ([Custom division symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505337/custom-division-symbol)).

To use it, I type `$a \newdiv b$` and it works fine, but I'd rather type `$a/b$` so that my code will be simpler to write, read, and also compatible with anyone who does not have the `\newdiv` macro defined. I would like to know if it is possible to have Latex output my custom command `\newdiv` every time I type a solidus `/` inside math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `/` mathcode `"8000` then it acts as if it were active.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\newdiv{:::whatever::::}

\mathcode`/="8000
{\catcode`\/=\active
\global\let/\newdiv}


\begin{document}

$1/2$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Can you explain what "giving `/` mathcode "8000  " means? What about "it acts as if it were active"?

Comment: Is this unadvisable in any way?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos “making `/` active” means making `/` behave as if it were a command (in this case, equal to `\newdiv`). “giving `/` mathcode "8000” is kind of like saying “make `/` active only in math”

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos making things active in text is how babel shorthands work if you are familiar with that, the mathcode"8000 feature is related but somewhat safer I would say. It is safe enough in practice.